# OpenID Connect - Implicit Flow with Javascript app using JWT to authenticate with a REST API

Tags: security, openid-connect

I am developing a Javascript app + REST API.

I want users to authenticate with the app (and underlying REST API) via an OpenID Connect Provider for SSO purposes.

Using the Implicit flow I can get an ID token (JWT) identifying the user to my javascript app. I was hoping that I could then send this JWT in the Authorize header in requests to my REST API to authenticate the user. However, the problem with this approach is that the 'aud' field of the JWT won't be for the REST API server, it would be for the javascript app.

Does this mean Implicit flow is not suitable for my use case, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implicit Flow is designed for untrusted clients (such as JavaScript) to obtain identity and also (optionally) access tokens.

With OpenID Connect your authentication request must contain id_token in the response_type parameter, but it can also include token in the parameter too. See 3.2.2.1 in the spec (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitAuthRequest)

e.g.

```
GET /authorize?
response_type=id_token%20token
&client_id=s6BhdRkqt3
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb
&scope=openid%20profile
&state=af0ifjsldkj
&nonce=n-0S6_WzA2Mj HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
```

id_token means that you will get back the ID token which you have mentioned. The token means that it will also return you an access token, which is what you would use for accessing your REST api.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that makes sense.. however the point where I am confused is using the access token for my REST api. Say I am using Google as an OIDC provider, this will provide me an access token for accessing Google APIs but not my REST api... unless there is someway my REST api can validate an access token returned by Google..?

Comment: It's taken me a while but I think I have it figured out now! The confusion was that I am actually trying to achieve two things (somewhat beyond the scope of my original question) 1. Identity federation - my Javascript API/REST API is just one component of a wider system that needs to work with a central identity provider. 2. Delegated access - other parties need to be able to access the REST API on user's behalf.

Comment: So my options are A) Have an Authorization server that both acts as an identity provider and issues access tokens that can be used with my REST API (requires REST API to be able to validate said tokens by some means, which is beyond the OAuth2 spec), or B) Have my REST API act as both an Authorization and Resource server with it's own tokens, that happens to use an external OIDC identity provider to authenticate users. (Excuse my rambling - this is a brain dump of what I have finally concluded after weeks of investigation, hopefully it's helpful to someone else)

Comment: if you are in the dotnet world, have you looked at the thinktecture IdentityServer3? It is open source and has good examples of requesting API access tokens as well as id_token, and using scopes to protect the api resources. it might be worth a look.

Comment: I'm in Java land :) but will still check it out to see what I can learn from an architectural point of view

Comment: @James When I host my own Open ID provider and use the implicit flow (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth), do I understand the spec correctly that Client will NOT receive "access_token" in the callback and uses the "id_token" to authenticate every subsequent API request?

Comment: @tiblu If you are going to make subsequent API requests then I believe you should be using an access token to authorise those requests. The ID token is used to prove the identity of the user to the client application, not to authorise API requests. In the Implicit flow, access tokens are optional for the case where you only need to know the user's identity and not make subsequent requests to an API on the user's behalf. At least, this is my understanding - happy to be corrected by someone who actually groks this stuff.

Comment: @James Thanks! I guess you are right, the "id_token" does contain just about the data I need for authorizing subsequent requests to my API, it also contains some stuff I don't need. While I don't see a security concern in passing "id_token" around over HTTPS, the bloat is an argument, as it's transferred over the wire with every request. Also every example in Open ID for the Implicit Flow does use the "access_token" and never "id_token".